# How to Left Join 2 columns based on condition

Tags: sql

I can't come up with a working SQL code that gives me Outcome_Table.
Need to LEFT JOIN 2 columns from Table_B to Table_A where IF A.srid is null, it joins by odid ELSE joins by srid

Table_A

| Column A.* | A.srid | A.odid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 |  | 111 |
| Cell 2 |  | 222 |
| Cell 3 | qwe123 | 333 |
| Cell 4 | q1w2e3 | 444 |

Table_B

| Column B.* | B.srid | B.odid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | qwe123 | 555 |
| Cell 2 | q1w2e3 | 666 |
| Cell 3 |  | 111 |
| Cell 4 | 321ewq | 777 |
| Cell 5 | qwe123 | 555 |

Outcome_Table

| Column A.* | A.srid | A.odid | B.srid | B.odid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 |  | 111 |  | 111 |
| Cell 2 |  | 222 |  |  |
| Cell 3 | qwe123 | 333 | qwe123 | 555 |
| Cell 4 | q1w2e3 | 444 | q1w2e3 | 666 |

I've tried this SQL query:

```
SELECT Table_A.* , Table_B.odid, Table_B.srid
FROM Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.srid = Table_B.srid OR Table_A.odid = Table_B.odid
```

It appears to work extremely slow and not even sure/can't confirm if the results were true.
Cannot update my Outcome_Table in Power BI with this query.
Please, help me getting desired result in the Outcome_Table example.

Comment: What stops ***both*** Cell1 and Cell5 from TableB joining on to Cell3 from TableA?

Comment: If A.srid is NULL, does B.srid need to be NULL too?

Comment: @MatBailie We can have multiple rows with same B.srid & B.odid in Table_B, while having a single counterpart with in Table_A. Basically, nothing stops, but we don't need to duplicate rows in Table_A

Comment: @MatBailie "If A.srid is NULL, does B.srid need to be NULL too?" - Yes

Comment: Can you have multiple rows in TableB with the same `srid` but different `odid`, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with union all for two query like this below

```
SELECT Table_A.* , Table_B.odid, Table_B.srid
FROM Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.srid = Table_B.srid
where Table_A.srid is not null

Union all

SELECT Table_A.* , Table_B.odid, Table_B.srid
FROM Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON  Table_A.odid = Table_B.odid
where Table_A.srid is null
```